# liquibase <insert> : Insert current date

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to insert data using liquibase insert tag. It works fine when I am inputing a number to value tag .
But I am looking for a simple function that will take care of default date (current DateTime of database) even when I don't have it as part of my table definition.

Eg:

```
<changeSet id="abc_1" author="Me">
<insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ">
    <column name="name" value="Me"/>
    <column name="create_date" value ="1328055111692"/>
    <column name="profile_last_update" value="currentDateTimeFunction"/>
    <column name="group_name" value="BlahBlah"/>
</insert>
</changeSet>
```

here `<column name="create_date" value ="1328055111692"/>` works fine and it gets inserted in to the database. I also tried using `<defaultValueDate>` and `<valueDate>` but they also need some date input in specified format.

I am looking for some function like **currentDateTimeFunction** that would be converted to UNIX_TIMESTAMP() or SYSDATE or now() based on type of database I am using. Please help me.

Thank you,
Ramya

Comment: @Mark To be fair, his response is a different answer than the one he's thanking.

Answer (score 71):

What you you will have to do is use [changelog parameter](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html)s and
define a "now" or "current_timestamp" parameter that is replaced per database type.

At the top of your `<databaseChangeLog>`, normally just outside your `<changeset>`, add per-database definitions of the property like:

```
  <property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>
  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql"/>
  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="postgresql"/>
```

then in your changesets use

```
<column name="Join_date" defaultValueFunction="${now}"/>
```

Notice the use of defaultValueFunction that will let liquibase know
not to parse it as a date or quote it.

Comment: I find that defaultValueFunction isn't allowed in my changelog.  According to the popup that Netbeans offers me, I'm only allowed the following attributes that start with 'default': defaultBoolean defaultDate defaultComputed defaultNumeric.  I'm running liquibase 2.0.3, the most recent version, and have tried using the exact changelog header as shown in the 'changelog parameters' page you linked to.  Are you sure defaultValueFunction is available in the latest release, or is this a feature on trunk?

Comment: It may be new in trunk, or something that should be added since there is a valueFunction. defaultValueNumeric should work as well. That also should tell liquibase to not bother quoting the value.

Comment: Hi Nathan Voxland, I suffer the same issue since i cannot find the valueFuntion. There is not such thing on liquibase website about that value either. Can you give me some suggestion to solve this issue ?

Comment: @NathanVoxland, Do you know if the property is accessible from a csv file, as we are using a csv file to input all of our data.

Comment: Attribute 'defaultValueFunction' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'.
- in Oracle.

Comment: In liquibase 3.9.0 defaultValueFunction is not allowed here. I'm on sqlserver database and tried using GETDATE() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in the value of the property "now". Then trying to use defaultValueNumeric or defaultValueDate I'm getting null value for the date and using valueDate liquibase is parsing and failing.

Comment: @NathanVoxland Hi, I appreciate it has been some time since this was posted. However, I have implemented your solution in my project, and all worked fine at first. However, this was within my local environment, when my manager merged my branch into master, the build failed on our UAT version. We believe this is due to a difference in version between my SQL and the SQL used by our UAT. I tried simply adding a second property for the ``dbms="mysql"`` but it did not work. Do you have a potential solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Thank you for your reply. it was helpful. Below is what I did and it worked for me.

```
<property name="now" value="UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" dbms="mysql"/>
<changeSet id="emp_1" author="Me">
<insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ">
    <column name="EmpName" value="abc"/>
    <column name="Join_date" valueDate="${now}"/>
    <column name="Profile_last_update" valueDate="${now}"/>
    <column name="group_name" value="BlahBlah"/>
</insert>
</changeSet>
```

Thanks again,
Ramya

Answer (score 5):

If you are using DB2 then you could do the following:

```
<changeSet id="emp_1" author="Me">
<insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ">
    <column name="EmpName" value="abc"/>
    <column name="Join_date" valueDate="CURRENT TIMESTAMP"/>
    <column name="Profile_last_update" valueDate="CURRENT TIMESTAMP"/>
    <column name="group_name" value="BlahBlah"/>
</insert>
</changeset>
```

The resulting SQL is not quoted so it just calls the DB2 function.

Comment: This seems to work for MySQL too, except use "now()" instead of "CURRENT TIMESTAMP".

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way of doing it given as below

you can simply use valueDate="now()" for MySQL. Like in my case I did:

```
    <changeSet id="emp_1" author="Me">
       <insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ">
         <column name="last_updated_at" valueDate="now()"></column>
       </insert>
    </changeset>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Liquibase + Oracle:** **use valueComputed="SYSDATE"**

Worked with Oracle 11g:

```
    <insert tableName="SOMETABLE">
        <column name="ID" valueComputed="SOMETABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL" />
        <column name="USER_ID" value="123" />
        <column name="CREATED_DATE" valueComputed="SYSDATE" />      
    </insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted by Ramya and Adam D, works for PostgreSQL too.

Using the "property" tag, I had to change the dbms to `dbms="postgresql"` and to use a PostgreSQL function for "value" (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my case).

Without the "property" tag, I used `valueDate="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` in the "column" tag.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.9 and Liquibase 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use valueNumeric to execute functions, as it will prevent the wrapping of quotes around the value.

```
<column name="id" valueNumeric="uuid_generate_v4()"></column>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set **dbms** in insert tag.

then for date use *valueDate* field in **column** tag.

```
 <changeSet  author="name"  id="id_1">
    <insert tableName="table_name" dbms="oracle">
        <column  name="id" value="71"/>
        <column  name="description" value="test"/>
        <column  name="start_date" valueDate="2020-01-01"/>
        <column  name="end_date" valueDate="2021-01-01"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me with mysql DB.

```
<column name="LAST_MODIFIED_DATE" valueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neek's answer works well (although I had to use `valueComputed`), however, issues can arise with substitution in other parts of the code such as unit testing, so the following approach as per the Liquidbase [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/insert.html) worked:

```
<insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ" dbms="oracle">  
    <column name="profile_last_update" value="sysdate"/>  
</insert>
<insert tableName="Emp" schemaName="XYZ" dbms="postgresql, mysql">  
    <column name="profile_last_update" value="now()"/>  
</insert>
```