# Liquibase: How to set the default value of a date column to be "now" in UTC format?

Tags: sql, liquibase

How do you set the default value of a date column to be "now" in UTC format? I think the answer involves the `defaultValueComputed` attribute on the [column element](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html).

The documentation states:

> defaultValueComputed  A value that is returned from a function or
>   procedure call. This attribute will contain the function to call.

What langauge is the function referred to supposed to be written in? Java? Is the function supposed to be the database vendor -specific date function I want to use? Is there any more documentation I can read on this topic?

Answer (score 55):

Maybe [this topic](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/mysql-timestamp-default-value) in the liquibase forum will help?

I think `defaultValueComputed` will take a database specific function to express "now". In mySQL it would be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` so it could look like this:

```
<createTable tableName="D_UserSession">
    <column name="ts" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
</createTable>
```

(Copied from the forum post.)

Comment: `defaultValueComputed="to_timestamp('2015-02-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')"` also works with Oracle

Comment: Note: this will only set the default value as the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, not when on update change the value(like last_updated_at) as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, checked with mysql and mariadb both same behaviour

Answer (score 17):

This should be:

```
<property name="now" value="now()" dbms="mysql,h2"/>
<property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>
<property name="now" value="sysdate" dbms="oracle"/>
<property name="now" value="getdate()" dbms="mssql"/>

<changeSet author="me" id="sample_usage_demo">
    <addColumn schemaName= "dbo" tableName="demo_table" >
        <column name="demo_column" type="datetime" defaultValueDate="${now}">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL, to use a DATETIME column with fractions of second like `DATETIME(6)` (microseconds precision), use default value of `NOW(6)` (caution: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)` for some reason produces an error with me using liquibase 3.5.3):

```
<column name="created_at" type="DATETIME(6)" defaultValueComputed="NOW(6)" >
   <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```

Note that the value will be stored internally in UTC, but read using the server's timezone settings (`@@global.time_zone`, `@@session.time_zone`).

Answer (score 4):

This works with SQlite:

```
<column name="last_updated_at" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultValueComputed="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```

Adding '$now' didn't work for me. I am using SQlite as the DB.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<property name="now" value="UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" dbms="mysql"/>
<column name="ts" type="timestamp" valueDate="${now}"/>
```

I found it thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9100388/3107952

Comment: Hey Pedro, perhaps you could accept people's suggested edits.  You have people saying that ${now} didn't work, but that's because you left out the fact that people need to define 'now' for each database they support:
<property name="now" value="UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" dbms="mysql"/>

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact, that the requested timezone **UTC** is not mentioned in all of the answers here, I'd like to state another set of solutions for different database vendors.

**Especially, the current answers here does not state the correct solution for Oracle.**

```xml
<changeSet logicalFilePath="my_changeset.xml"
   id="1"
   author="me"
   dbms="mariadb,h2">
   <addColumn tableName="MY_TABLE">
      <column name="MY_ZONED_DATE_TIME_COLUMN"
         type="timestamp(6)"
         defaultValueComputed="now()">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
   </addColumn>
</changeSet>

<changeSet logicalFilePath="my_changeset.xml"
   id="1"
   author="me"
   dbms="postgresql">
   <addColumn tableName="MY_TABLE">
      <column name="MY_ZONED_DATE_TIME_COLUMN"
         type="timestamp(6)"
         defaultValueComputed="timezone('UTC', now())">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
   </addColumn>
</changeSet>

<changeSet logicalFilePath="my_changeset.xml"
   id="1"
   author="me"
   dbms="oracle">
   <addColumn tableName="MY_TABLE">
      <column name="MY_ZONED_DATE_TIME_COLUMN"
         type="timestamp(6)"
         defaultValueComputed="sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)">
         <constraints nullable="false"/>
      </column>
   </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

(One may use properties, like showed in [Dominika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68939890/10816587), but we had some really bad experiences with properties in liquibase.)

---

Summary:

- `now()` is fine for MariaDB, MySql and H2v
- `now()` is not completely fine for H2, I just got a correct result starting the h2 database with UTC like `jdbc:h2:mem:./my_database;TIME ZONE=UTC` (h2database in version 2.x needed). Then `now()` is working for sure.
- I'm not sure about `current_timestamp` on PostgreSQL, but `timezone('UTC', now())` works. :)
- In Oracle, `sysdate` (mentioned in a few other answers here) is not enough, see as well ["How to get UTC value for SYSDATE on Oracle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157873/how-to-get-utc-value-for-sysdate-on-oracle), but `sys_extract_utc(systimestamp)` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `timestamp with time zone` as that will keep the timestamps in UTC as opposed to local server time, which might be problem if you have a multi-region setup.

You can readmore about the timezone part on [this Stack Overflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876218/difference-between-timestamps-with-without-time-zone-in-postgresql)

```
  databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 007
      author: joe
      changes:
        - addColumn:
            tableName: my_table
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: created_at
                  type: timestamp with time zone
        -  addDefaultValue:
             columnName:  created_at
             defaultValueComputed:  now()
             tableName:  my_table
```

Answer (score -1):

As liquibase is common changelog for any database, to make it generic you should not depend on any specific database like oracle, postegres, mysql instead it should be generic enough to work for any/every database.

Below is how it should be implemented :

```
<column name="time" type="${type.datetime}" defaultValueComputed="${column.datetime.defaultValue}"/>
```

This should work for all databases, for oracle, it inserts SYSTIMESTAMP as DATA_DEFAULT.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me using postgreSQL

Comment: Where do these expressions come from? For me this just fails silently.

Comment: this answer is incomplete